Проблемa с изменением Background в TreeViewItem
Нужно изменить задний фон выделенного элемента в дереве. Пишу стиль для TreeViewItem, попробовал сначала для Foregroung - работает, пробую с Background - не изменяется. Возможно ли дело в другом, из за чего фон может не изменяться?
Вот пример кода:
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemGray" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>



В данном вопросе есть пару ответов, которые мне помогли решить эту проблему - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048141/22350946

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

Вполне допустимо перевести ответы с англоязычного SO, если они вам помогли.
